# Passing values to JS using AJAX

Tags: java, servlets

I have a java servlet which Reads data from a text file ,The o/p is then passed to a JS using ajax,The problem is I am successfully fetching the data from file but after passing it to ajax ,getting empty String

Java Script-

```
function main()
    {
      var result;

        $.ajax({
            url:'insertPos',
        //  data: {data : data},
            type:'get',             
             success:function(value)    
            {
                 result= value;
                 console.log(result);//getting empty string

            }

        });

    }
```

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");    
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/Workspace1/JAVA1/Sample/DATA.txt"));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
               String  value = sb.toString();
             System.out.println(value);


        } finally {
            br.close();
        }

    }
```

If I print in console  console.log(result);//getting empty string

Comment: you are using ` System.out.println(value);` !! this will not write the send the value to ajax.

Comment: Here, you don't put anything to response writer.

Answer (score 2):

Change your servlet with below code.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");    
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/Workspace1/JAVA1/Sample/DATA.txt"));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
               String  value = sb.toString();
               out.write(value);//you just need to use out that printwriter object.


        } finally {
            br.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Getting this error-GET insertPos
500 Internal Server Error
17ms

Comment: D:\Workspace1\JAVA1\Sample\DATA.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: ohh...you said that you can read file properly.....But not getting in ajax response. so you made this mistake. for file is it exist on the same path?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
out.write(value);
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(value);
```